# TForm parent property

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am currently (in some cases dependant on a configuration file) parenting multiple forms.

That is to say one parent formcould have multiple child forms.

The problem I have is that when I minimise a child form and the parent window is not currently maximised (I'm setting the form size of the parent based on a configuration file) I lose the child forms icon, thus can't restore it.

If the parent form was maximised before doing this then I still have the icon and CAN restore it..

In my case I want the parent form to be a bounding box (still has to be a form though)thus has no tile bar so maximise can't be achieved.

I need to be able to set this parenting up on the fly.

Looked at MDI forms (cant use a whole MDI application) but heard that they don't work well being set on the fly..

Does anybody have any tips of the best approach on this one. I'm not expecting free code but some guidance would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally NOT a good idea to set the `Parent` of a `TForm` at all, let alone to another `TForm`.  A better solution is to put your child content onto a `TFrame` instead, and then set the `Parent` for that as needed.  This gives you more control over how and where the `TFrame` is displayed.  You can then provide your own UI for hiding and showing your `TFrame` instances as needed.  If you need a given `TFrame` to be free-floating, simply instantiate a blank `TForm` and set it as the `Parent` for that `TFrame`.

Comment: I see. I might have to redesign a few things then.

Comment: Sorry cut that short by pressing enter for new line :-). Frames are transparent but if I want to place controls onto my form and there is a frame parented on it (programatically). Do I need to parent the controls onto the frame instead of the form so that I can see them. Just mocked up a dummy form and parented a frame to the form. In the designer I placed a button on the form but the frame was placed on top of the button. I am going to have many cases where I will need a bitmap drawn on a form etc. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: The point is to NOT put your content on a `TForm` unless the user needs to drag your content around the screen. You can put all of your content on a `TFrame` and then place it on a `TPanel` or whatever other `Parent` container you want. If you then want your content to be draggable around the screen, you can place the `TFrame` on a blank `TForm` and set the frame's `Align` property to `alClient` to fill the entire `TForm`. The user will never know the difference.

Comment: Think of a `TFrame` like a cross between a non-floating `TForm` and a `TPanel` on steriods.  You can design it at design-time just like you can with a `TForm` or a `TDataModule`, but you can also put it in your Object Repository and/or on the Component Palette, and then make duplicates of it (with all its child controls intact) at design-time and/or run-time as needed.  Since it is not a `TForm` itself, you have to place it onto a `Parent` control to make it visible, but it will blend in with the rest of your UI more seemlessly than an embedded `TForm` would, without the pitfalls.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations. They have been very helpful. I have been playing around with the concept in a dummy application. This does make sense. I am glad that I asked the question now as it seems parenting two forms together is not a very good idea at all. I shall try it out and if I run into any problems I will report back to this post but for now thanks for your help! :-). Joe